# Properly backporting generic collections

Tags: python-3.x, generics, collections, abc, backport

In Python 3.9 it is now possible to use `collections.abc` with generics, meaning code such as this is possible:

```py
import collections.abc
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class MySequence(collections.abc.Sequence[T]):
    ...
```

In Python 3.8, however, this is not possible. Instead, one must use the `typing` module for generics. I'm wondering what the proper way to go about this is. Right now I'm doing the following:

```py
import sys
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    import collections.abc, typing

    class ABC_Sequence(collections.abc.Sequence, typing.Sequence[T]):
        pass

else:
    from collections.abc import Sequence as ABC_Sequence


class MySequence(ABC_Sequence[T]):
    ...
```

Is this the proper way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems some linters such as `mypy` do not like the above code. In particular, `mypy` complains that duplicate base classes are used even though `collections.abc.Sequence` is not the same as `typing.Sequence`. It seems the correct fix is to actually subclass `typing.Sequence` for lower versions.

```py
import collections.abc
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    from typing import Sequence
else:
    from collections.abc import Sequence


class MySequence(Sequence[T]):
    ...


# For `isinstance` checks at runtime.
if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    collections.abc.Sequence.register(MySequence)
```